# CSS increase padding from font-size not linear

Tags: css, responsive-design, font-size

I have an element that have a `padding` based on the `font-size` by using the `em` unit. But I need to increase the padding for 5px each time the `font-size` increase of 1px. I'm not even sure if it's possible using the `calc()` function or an other way ?

```css
.test {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 1.875em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

@media (min-width: 300px) {
  .test {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .test {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
</div>
```

My aim is not to have to write `media-queries` inside the element/component, it should only depends on the font-size of its parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your font-size and thereby 1em increases by 1px and the padding should increase by 5px for every pixel of font-size above 16px, padding should be `calc(1.875 * 16px + ((1em - 16px) * 5))` - the original padding at 16px (1.875 * 16px) plus the difference of the font-size to 16px times 5.

Comment: Thanks it works. Just a little issue to fix,when using a multiplcation or division, one of the parts must be unitless, to the right calc is => `calc((1.875 * 16px) + ((1em - 16px) * 5));` just removing the last `px` from `5px`.

Comment: @Mushr00m Th.anks for pointing that out - I edited my answer accordingly